# How can I access the WebDriver module from within an AcceptanceTester?

Tags: codeception

I have a test, where I an trying to change the configuration:

```
$this->getModule('WebDriver')->_reconfigure([...]);
```

This shows what I am trying to do under "Dynamic Configration": http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#.VnXNjq6rTUI

Edit:
It appears that I have to call this on the moduleContainer, but this is located at:

```
$I->scenario->test->moduleContainer->getModule('WebDriver')->_getConfig('url');
```

However $test is under private access, and there is no getTest() method.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says: `You may call it from a helper class and pass in all the fields you want to change.`

Add reconfigure method to your Acceptance helper and call it from your test.